# correct way to get the gpio number from the device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

Is this

```c
of_get_named_gpio(child, "gpio-name", 0);
```

a correct way to get the GPIO number? Where the corresponding device tree is as below:

```
gpio-name = <&gpio0 21 0>;
```

I get this error:

> probe of  failed with error -2

What does error code `-2` represents? Is this a device tree parsing error?

Comment: Have you checked `dmesg` output? There should be some related message to your `of_get_named_gpio()` call, that would explain what is the actual error.

Comment: `-ENOENT` means there is no such GPIO. DT as well as other resource provides (ACPI, built-in device properties) has a specific pattern for GPIOs, i.e. `<NAME>-gpios`, where you use `<NAME>` as parameter to a call `of_get_named_gpio(child, "<NAME>")`. In any case I highly recommend not to use such API and directly get GPIO using its API.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko but such types of APIs have alreaady been used in the existing drivers in the kernel. see this : http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/leds/leds-ns2.c , what API you are referring to , can you please post it !

Comment: `gpiod_*()` kind of calls. It doesn't matter what **has been** used since new APIs **are coming** all the time.

Answer (score 1):

**This snap-shot of the code shows how to get/set the particular GPIO. it is a tested code.**

```
     struct device_node *np = client->dev.of_node;
     int gpio;
     u8 buf[MAX_I2C_DATA_LEN];   
     int ret, tries = 0;

     if (!np)
             return -ENODEV;            

     gpio = of_get_named_gpio(np, "**gpio-name-used-in-dts-file**", 0); 
     if (!gpio_is_valid(gpio))
             return -ENODEV;            

     ret = gpio_request(gpio, "egalax_irq");  
     if (ret < 0) {            
          dev_err(&client->dev,
         "request gpio failed, cannot wake up controller: %d\n",ret);
             return ret;
     }   

     gpio_direction_output(gpio, 1); 
     ret = gpio_get_value(gpio);

     ""ret"" Will have gpio value.
```